# iPad style navbar on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

Hey, on iPad the navigation bar is normally silver and on the iPhone it's normally blue. Is there any easy way to make the silver navbar on iPhone app?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the color of your navigation bar, the easiest way to do this would be to add your navigation bar in IB, then click on the navigation bar's attributes panel.  Change the tint color to whatever color you would like in there and it will show up accordingly on your app.  Similarly, if you are adding the navigation bar programmatically, you should be able to set the tint color yourself with something along the lines of `myNavBar.tintColor = [UIColor someColor];`.  I hope this helps.

Comment: If you're looking for the tint values, I'm using RGB(240,241,243) on the iPhone to fairly closely match the iPad navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5 this can be easily achieved without any manual tinkering. Read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) up.